# Request-Scoped Services

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

From what I understood now nestjs creates all the services when the application starts, maybe I'm using it wrong is there a way to configure NestJs to create services based on request? Like each time a request is done some services which are used on that request are recreated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the release of nest.js 6.0, [injection scopes](https://docs.nestjs.com/providers#scopes) were added. With this, you can choose one of the following three scopes for your providers:

- **SINGLETON**: Default behavior. One instance of your provider is used for the whole application
- **TRANSIENT**: A dedicated instance of your provider is created for every provider that injects it.
- **REQUEST**: For each request, a new provider is created.

⚠️ Caution: The injection scope will bubble up in your dependency chain.  ⚠️

Example: If `UsersController` (singleton scope) injects `UsersService` (singleton scope) that injects `OtherService` (request scope), then both `UsersController` and `UsersService` will automatically become request-scoped.

#### Usage

Either add it to the `@Injectable()` decorator:

```
@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class UsersService {}
```

Or set it for custom providers in your module definition:

```
{
  provide: 'CACHE_MANAGER',
  useClass: CacheManager,
  scope: Scope.TRANSIENT,
}
```

Comment: Be aware - In the current version `Scope.REQUEST` services doesn't work for `nest/cqrs` Commands and Queries

Comment: I guess transient scope bubbles up the injection chain too, doesn't it?

Comment: @fabianski Yes, it will also bubble up. The impact on the performance is negligible though as the instantiation is done on startup and not on _every_ request. I will rephrase though, this is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with a build-in request-scope dependency injection mechanism  
https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes  
but it has serious drawbacks according to the documentation:

> Scope bubbles up the injection chain. A controller that depends on a request-scoped provider will, itself, be request-scoped.

> Using request-scoped providers will have an impact on application performance. While Nest tries to cache as much metadata as possible, it will still have to create an instance of your class on each request. Hence, it will slow down your average response time and overall benchmarking result. Unless a provider must be request-scoped, it is strongly recommended that you use the default singleton scope.

Recently I have created request-scope implementation for NestJS free from bubbling up the injection chain and performance impact.

https://github.com/kugacz/nj-request-scope

To use it first you have to add import of RequestScopeModule in the module class decorator:

```
import { RequestScopeModule } from 'nj-request-scope';

@Module({
    imports: [RequestScopeModule],
})
```

Next, there are two ways of request-scope injection:

1. Inject express request object into class constructor with NJRS_REQUEST token:

```
import { NJRS_REQUEST } from 'nj-request-scope';
[...]
constructor(@Inject(NJRS_REQUEST) private readonly request: Request) {}
```

2. Change class inject scope to request-scope with @RequestScope() decorator:

```
import { RequestScope } from 'nj-request-scope';

@Injectable()
@RequestScope()
export class RequestScopeService {
```

You can find example implementations in this repository: https://github.com/kugacz/nj-request-scope-example
[NestJS what is the best practice to initialise and pass request context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65086829/nestjs-what-is-the-best-practice-to-initialise-and-pass-request-context/70073910#70073910)
I think you can use nj-request-scope package I wrote. It's free from bubbles up injection chain and performance issues:

https://github.com/kugacz/nj-request-scope

First, you have to add import of `RequestScopeModule` in the module class decorator:

```
import { RequestScopeModule } from 'nj-request-scope';

@Module({
    imports: [RequestScopeModule],
})
```

and then your `RequestContext` class can be written like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request } from 'express';
import { IncomingHttpHeaders } from 'http';
import { RequestScope } from 'nj-request-scope';
import { NJRS_REQUEST } from 'nj-request-scope';

@Injectable()
@RequestScope()
export class RequestContext {
    public headers: IncomingHttpHeaders;
    ....

    constructor(@Inject(NJRS_REQUEST) private readonly request: Request) {
        this.headers = request.headers;
    }
}
```

In that case, a new instance of `RequestContext` class will be created for every request. So, you can store any request-scope information inside this class. Injecting this class into any part of your application won't cause a bubble up injection chain.

Another approach is like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request } from 'express';
import { IncomingHttpHeaders } from 'http';
import { NJRS_REQUEST } from 'nj-request-scope';

@Injectable()
export class RequestContext {

    constructor(@Inject(NJRS_REQUEST) private readonly request: Request) {
    }

    public get headers(): IncomingHttpHeaders {
        return this.request.headers;
    }
}
```

In that case `RequestContext` class is singleton-scope and only `request` field is request-scope. So, you can't store any request-scoped information directly in `RequestContext` class rather you have to read request-scoped data directly from the request object via getters. Also, injecting this class into any part of your application won't cause a bubble up injection chain.

Simple nj-request-scope package usage examples you can find here: https://github.com/kugacz/nj-request-scope-example

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30408819)

Answer (score 1):

### Update Jan 19

This will be possible in nest.js 6.0, see this [pull request](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/pull/1405).

---

As Kamil wrote in this [issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/953#issuecomment-413348496):

> Once async-hooks feature (it is still experimental in node 10) is
> stable, we'll think about providing a built-in solution for
> request-scoped instances.

So for now, this does not seem to be possible yet. You can only mark entire modules as [`SingleScope`](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/common/decorators/modules/single-scope.decorator.ts) vs the default singleton behavior. With `SingleScope`, a new instance of the module will be created for each import.

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to use di to be able to mark an entire endpoint to run in a
>   transaction without having to write some specific code for the
>   endpoints. Instead of using di there is a package which helps us to
>   create resources based on a callback chain called `cls-hooked` which
>   is based on what Kim Kern writed in his response, `async-hooks` using
>   This I was able to start a transaction when an enpoint is called and
>   stop it once the enpoint is done, since I use `typeorm` as a db orm I
>   was able to use [this
>   solution](https://github.com/odavid/typeorm-transactional-cls-hooked)